# W/System: A resource failed to call close retrofit2

Tags: java, android, api, resources, retrofit2

I am mastering retrofit2. Wrote a program for parsing json with api. The program works correctly, so I decided to try on another api, changed the baseUrl (and everything else related to this).

The program generates an error (errors, in this case, may be different). The error text itself is most likely not important. It is important that after fixing the error, or even returning the api, with which everything worked correctly, the android studio continues to issue the same error.

At the end of the error, in white letters, the text is added:

```
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
    A resource failed to call close.
```

cod:

```
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("qotd_date")
    @Expose
    private String qotdDate;
    @SerializedName("quote")
    @Expose
    private Quote quote;

    public String getQotdDate() {
        return qotdDate;
    }

    public void setQotdDate(String qotdDate) {
        this.qotdDate = qotdDate;
    }

}
```

class Quote:

```
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Quote {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("dialogue")
    @Expose
    private Boolean dialogue;
    @SerializedName("private")
    @Expose
    private Boolean _private;
    @SerializedName("tags")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> tags = null;
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;
    @SerializedName("favorites_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer favoritesCount;
    @SerializedName("upvotes_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer upvotesCount;
    @SerializedName("downvotes_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer downvotesCount;
    @SerializedName("author")
    @Expose
    private String author;
    @SerializedName("author_permalink")
    @Expose
    private String authorPermalink;
    @SerializedName("body")
    @Expose
    private String body;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Boolean getDialogue() {
        return dialogue;
    }

    public void setDialogue(Boolean dialogue) {
        this.dialogue = dialogue;
    }

    public Boolean getPrivate() {
        return _private;
    }

    public void setPrivate(Boolean _private) {
        this._private = _private;
    }

    public List<Object> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(List<Object> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Integer getFavoritesCount() {
        return favoritesCount;
    }

    public void setFavoritesCount(Integer favoritesCount) {
        this.favoritesCount = favoritesCount;
    }

    public Integer getUpvotesCount() {
        return upvotesCount;
    }

    public void setUpvotesCount(Integer upvotesCount) {
        this.upvotesCount = upvotesCount;
    }

    public Integer getDownvotesCount() {
        return downvotesCount;
    }

    public void setDownvotesCount(Integer downvotesCount) {
        this.downvotesCount = downvotesCount;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getAuthorPermalink() {
        return authorPermalink;
    }

    public void setAuthorPermalink(String authorPermalink) {
        this.authorPermalink = authorPermalink;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

}
```

interface Client:

```
public interface Client {

    @GET("qotd")
    Call <Example> reposForUser();
}
```

class MyAdapter:

```
    public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Example> {
    
        private Context context;
        private Example values;
    
        public MyAdapter(Context context, Example values) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_item_pagination, Collections.singletonList(values));
    
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }
    
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
    
            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater =
                        (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_pagination, parent, false);
            }
    
            TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_item_pagination_text);
    
            Example item = values;
            String message = item.getQotdDate();
            textView.setText(message);
    
            return row;
        }
    }

class MainActivity:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pagination_list);


        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://favqs.com/api/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

        Client client = retrofit.create(Client.class);
        Call <Example> call = client.reposForUser();
        Log.d("mylog1","внешний log");
        call.enqueue(new Callback/*<List*/<Example>/*>*/() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call <Example> call, Response <Example> response) {
                Example repos = response.body();
                Log.d("mylog1", String.valueOf(repos));
                Log.d("mylog1","mylog");

                listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, repos));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call <Example> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: add your code in question.

Comment: @sak, I added code

Comment: try calling response.body().close();

Comment: @sak, when I add the line response.body (). close (); , the close () method is highlighted in red (I added a screenshot of the code in the question)